# Mantener opciones seleccionadas combobox múltiple

Tags: php, mysql, select, combobox

Tengo un código que crea un menú desplegable múltiple a partir de una base de datos mysql y que carga los datos a una tabla al hacer click en un botón y con una opción marcada por defecto al cargar la página.

Necesitaría que la tabla se genere directamente al cargar la página la primera vez con esa opción por defecto y que el desplegable mantenga las opciones seleccionadas después de hacer click en el botón.

Este es el código:

```
<?php
include 'conBBDD_1.php';
$db_handle = new conBBDD();
$TourResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT bbcTour FROM concerts ORDER BY bbcDate DESC");
?>

<form method="POST" name="Search" action="example.php">
        
<?php
  if (! empty($TourResult)) {
        $format = "Tour 2020";
        $select = 'selected';
        echo "<select name='tour[]' id='bb_tour' multiple='multiple'>";
   foreach ($TourResult as $key => $value) {
   echo "<option value='" . $TourResult[$key]['bbcTour']."'";
   if($TourResult[$key]['bbcTour']==$format) // to select one option only
            echo $select. ">";
        else
            echo ">";
        
            echo $TourResult[$key]['bbcTour'].'</option>' . "\n";
      }
    }
            echo "</select>";
?>
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="OK">
</form>
```

---

¿cómo podría hacer que el valor por default `$format` seleccionara todos los valores en lugar de uno solo?

Gracias.

```
$seleccionados = (isset($_POST['tour'])) ? $_POST['tour'] : [$format];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes conocer los elementos que ya se seleccionaron y puedes hacerlo con una asignación ternaria: `$seleccionados = (isset($_POST['tour'])) ? $_POST['tour'] : [];` (comentarios en el código)

Dentro del ciclo puedes simplificar el código, asignando a la variable `$select` el valor ' selected' solo si es igual  a "Tour 2020" (valor por default) o está en el array `$seleccionados`, de lo contrario, queda como cadena vacía. Esto se hace también con asignación ternaria.

Entonces, con un solo `echo` puedes generar todo el contenido de `<option ..>`, sin concatenar y solo escapando las comillas dobles.

```
<?php
include 'conBBDD_1.php';
$db_handle = new conBBDD();
$TourResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT bbcTour FROM concerts ORDER BY bbcDate DESC");
// Define el valor por default desde el inicio
$format = "Tour 2020";

// (Si ya se procesó el formulario)
// entonces ? Obtener los que se seleccionaron
// de lo contrario : Crear un array vacío
$seleccionados = (isset($_POST['tour'])) ? $_POST['tour'] : [];
?>

<form method="POST" name="Search" action="example.php">

<?php
if (! empty($TourResult)) {
    echo "<select name='tour[]' id='bb_tour' multiple='multiple'>";
    foreach ($TourResult as $key => $val) {
        $value = $val['bbcTour'];
        // Seleccionado si es valor por default o si está en la lista de seleccionados
        $select = ($value == $format || in_array($value, $seleccionados)) ? ' selected' : '';
        echo "<option value=\"$value\"$selected>$value</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
?>
<input type="submit" id="button" value="OK">
</form>
```

Probablemente sea mejor agregar el valor por default solo cuando no se ha procesado el formulario y quedaría así:

```
$seleccionados = (isset($_POST['tour'])) ? $_POST['tour'] : [$format];
```

Y cambiar la verificación dentro del ciclo para no forzar el valor por default si el usuario no lo eligió

```
$select = (in_array($value, $seleccionados)) ? ' selected' : '';
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no consigo que funcione. La variable $value no carga el contenido de bbcTour y en su lugar aparece "Array" en las opciones del combo.

Comment: Cierto, faltaba el índice `['bbcTour']`, modifiqué el ciclo y agregué otra variable.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias!

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, por favor márcala como aceptada. ¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿cómo podría hacer que el valor por default $format seleccionara todos los valores en lugar de uno solo?

Gracias.